# Double series summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for analytic formula for double series
$$
\sum_{n,k = 0}^{\infty}\cfrac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(2n+1)(2k+1)\left((2n+1)^2 + (2k+1)^2\right)}
$$
It seems that the series is conditionally convergent, at least D'Alamber test gives $$\lim \frac{a_{n+1,k}}{a_{n,k}} = 1$$.
I have not ever come across double series and means to sum them up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $\int_{[1,+\infty)^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{xy(x^2+y^2)}=\log\sqrt{2}$, the double series is absolutely convergent. Moreover, from the identity $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{a^2}\cdot\frac{e^{-bx}}{x}\,dx = \frac{1}{ab(a^2+b^2)}$$ we have that the value of such a series is someway related to $\zeta(3)$.

Comment: In particular, from the last identity we have that the value of the series is given by integrating a triangle wave against $\arctan(e^{-x})$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and clear hint! I'll try to use it

Comment: But it seems that you've made a typo in the second identity: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{a^2}\frac{e^{-bx}}{b}\,dx = \frac{1}{ab(a^2 + b^2)}$$